# Foreground service stops after some time if phone kept in sleep mode

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation, foreground-service

I have developed an application that tracks user's location and records the distance traveled by the user. To make the app robust, I have used foreground service that spawns a thread with a handler inside it. The FusedLocationProvider sends location updates to the thread via handler and thread calculates distance traveled and sends the location to the server.

The service is closed when the user closes the application.

However, the service stops sometimes when the device is kept in sleep mode.
How can I make the foreground service always running as long as the user does not manually close the application?

Comment: Code please....

Comment: Also error please....

Comment: no error..it just stops running after some time...without any exception

Comment: What is the android version of the device?

Comment: mostly devices are on 7.0..however is problem is encountered more on custom ROM devices such as Oppo, Vivo, MI etc running android 5.0+

Comment: The service is closed when the user closes the application - how you are checking app is closed?
device is kept in sleep mode - you mean app is in foreground but device goes to sleep?

Comment: I stopped the service in on destroy of the activity that creates the service...and yes, the app remains in foreground but user locks the phone by power button putting device in sleep mode...after which the service terminates automatically without any callback